# React-table. how to set the width of columns after receiving them from the server (fetch request)

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I saved data to the server after resize columns, and then after reloading browser page I try to set the column width - which I got from server/
I tried from this example but not successfully
Can you please give me example how correctly do this?
p.s sorry about my English . I hope I said clearly

added chunk of my code

```
useEffect(() => {
....
fetch(url, requestOptions)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) =>
console.log(">>>WIDTH>>>", data.columnResizing); // here is ok - I got  for example {name: 255}
setResizeColumns(data.columnResizing); // my own func setResizeColumns
})
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently no direct apis exists for this, try to make use of `action` at https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/src/plugin-hooks/useResizeColumns.js#L203